# How to determine on CAF Sender that ad break is playing?

Tags: google-cast

I'm working with a CAF receiver that implements ad breaks. On the receiver side ads play correctly.

According to the documentation https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/ad_breaks 
"While a break is playing, CAF Receiver SDK broadcasts MediaStatus with breakStatus to all connected senders. Senders can use this information to update UIs and suppress any seek operations."

On the sender (chrome) before an ad break plays the breakStatus is undefined. When a break begins to play then breakStatus is populated. Then after a break is complete the breakStatus does not go back to undefined. To see these results I've been manually running: `window.cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().getCurrentSession().getMediaSession()`.

My plan was to use the presence of breakStatus to indicate that an ad break is playing. I'm having trouble finding more information about this break status broadcast. I feel like there should be some event listener but I have not been able to find it https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/cast.framework#.RemotePlayerEventType.

Is there an alternative solution to determining if a ad break is currently playing?

Comment: I think that's the expected behavior of the [`BreakStatus Class`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.media.BreakStatus). The `currentBreakTime` and `currentBreakClipTime` arguments value should be time elapsed after current break starts and time after current break clip starts. This means that the value is undefined before an ad break plays. Status of break, if receiver is playing break. This field will be defined only when receiver is playing break.

Comment: @jess I believe there may have been an issue with the MediaSession not replacing the existing breakStatus object with an undefined value after the break completed. It is resolved now that they are using an empty object instead of undefined.

Comment: That's cool. Glad they fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue is resolved with the March 25th CAF Receiver update https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes

By setting the breakStatus to an empty object it updates on the sender side.